# Choosing between tf.InteractiveSession() and tf.Session()

Tags: python, tensorflow

While I understood the differences between `tf.InteractiveSession()` and `tf.Session()` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41791469/difference-between-tf-session-and-tf-interactivesession), which one is preferable for large projects and creating libraries?
For example, why do libraries like Sonnet use `tf.Session()` over `tf.InteractiveSession()` despite the latter's advantages listed in that answer?

Comment: If you look at source code for InteractiveSession in [session.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/client/session.py#L1556), you can see it's just a few lines of code wrapping Session. Essentially the only difference is that it registers session as the default session. If you envision use-cases with more than one session, use regular tf.Session

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, there is no other limitation of `tf.InteractiveSession()` otherwise, am I right? 
Thanks for your help