# Which values to use when feeding placeholders in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the code below, there are a number of tensor operations and calculations. I'd like to see the results of some of those calculations so I can better understand them. Specifically I'd like to see what h looks like during graph execution using `print(Session.Run(h))`. However, the calculations are dependent on the placeholder X. So in order to see them I need to use a feed dictionary.

I have read through this SO question: [How to feed a placeholder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33810990/how-to-feed-a-placeholder) and several others. I still don't know what I should be feeding into this placeholder.

To see the value of h, how, or rather what am I supposed to put in the feed dictionary when trying to print it?

```
def expand_tile(value, size):
    """Add a new axis of given size."""
    value = tf.convert_to_tensor(value, name='value')
    ndims = value.shape.ndims
    return tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(value, axis=0), [size] + [1]*ndims)

def positions_for(tokens, past_length):
    batch_size = tf.shape(tokens)[0]
    nsteps = tf.shape(tokens)[1]
    return expand_tile(past_length + tf.range(nsteps), batch_size)


def model(hparams, X, past=None, scope='model', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    with tf.variable_scope(scope, reuse=reuse):
        results = {}

        batch_size = 1
        X = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, None])

        batch, sequence = shape_list(X)

        wpe = tf.get_variable('wpe', [1024, 768],
                             initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01))
        wte = tf.get_variable('wte', [50256, 768],
                             initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02))
        past_length = 0 if past is None else tf.shape(past)[-2]
        h = tf.gather(wte, X) + tf.gather(wpe, positions_for(X, past_length))
```

Comment: Use an interactive session like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41791469/whats-the-difference-between-tf-session-and-tf-interactivesession).

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your help. I did try using tf.InteractiveSession() and print(h.eval()). I received the error message saying I need to feed values to the placeholder X with shape (1, ?). Is that what you meant to use?

Answer (score 0):

When you use an interactive session you can just set the values in python x = 57, bypassing the placeholder entirely, then evaluate the rest of the graph however you want.